UKF ignores sensor data
Below is a complete listing of UKF for IMU sensor. No installation, except for FilterPy: should just run.
The problem is, it uses IMU orientation, but ignores IMU angular speed and linear acceleration: they just do not affect the result. Note also the GPS and Landmarks sensor data (commented out). If uncommented, filter successfully uses them as well... but not IMU angular speed and linear acceleration...
Please help.
# Based on Kalman and Bayesian Filters in Python, Roger R Labbe Jr
# Use: MIT license

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

import copy

import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

from math import tan, sin, cos, sqrt
from math import cos, sin, atan2, pi

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from filterpy.kalman import UnscentedKalmanFilter as UKF
from filterpy.common import Q_discrete_white_noise
from filterpy.kalman import JulierSigmaPoints
from filterpy.kalman import unscented_transform, MerweScaledSigmaPoints
from filterpy.stats import plot_covariance_ellipse

# gps: x,y
#
# imu: orientation (roll, pitch, yaw), angular velocity (vx, vy, vz), linear acceleration (ax, ay, az)
# imu currently used: orientation (yaw), angular velocity (vz), linear acceleration (ax, ay)
#
# landmarks: data in format [dist_1, bearing_1, dist_2, bearing_2,...]
 
dictSensors = { }
arrHideLandmarks = []
arr_npPrediction = None
#currentCommand = None
sensorData = {}

# coordinates and orientation:
## x = [x, y, θ]T
## x = [x, y, θ, vz]T
# x = [x, y, θ, vz, ax, ay]T
nNumOfStateParams = 6
# control input u is the commanded velocity and steering angle
# u = [v, α]T
# return: x, y, heading
def move(x, dt, u):
    vel = u[0]  # Commanded linear velocity
    angularVelZ = u[1]  # Commanded angular velocity around Z-axis (vz)
    #print(u[1], x[3])

    heading = x[2]  # Robot's current orientation (θ)
    heading = normalize_angle(heading + angularVelZ * dt)

    # Linear accelerations in the robot's frame, ax is where robot is facing
    ax_robot = x[4]
    ay_robot = x[5]

    #dist = vel * dt 

    vx = vel * cos(heading)
    vy = vel * sin(heading)

    # Transform linear accelerations from robot's frame to global frame
    ax_global = ax_robot * cos(heading) - ay_robot * sin(heading)
    ay_global = ax_robot * sin(heading) + ay_robot * cos(heading)

    # Update linear velocities based on linear accelerations in the global frame
    vx = vx + dt * ax_global  # Update vx with linear acceleration ax in global frame
    vy = vy + dt * ay_global  # Update vy with linear acceleration ay in global frame

    # Calculate the new position
    new_x = x[0] + (vx * dt) #* cos(normalize_angle(heading + angularVelZ * dt))
    new_y = x[1] + (vy * dt) #* sin(normalize_angle(heading + angularVelZ * dt))

    # return np.array([new_x, new_y, new_theta, new_vz, ax_robot, ay_robot])

    return np.array([
        #x[0] + dist*cos(normalize_angle(heading + angularVelZ * dt)), 
        #x[1] + dist*sin(normalize_angle(heading + angularVelZ * dt)), 
        new_x, 
        new_y,
        heading,
        normalize_angle(angularVelZ), 
        ax_robot, 
        ay_robot])

# ---

def normalize_angle(x):
    x = x % (2 * np.pi)         # force in range [0, 2 pi)
    if x > np.pi:               # move to [-pi, pi)
        x -= 2 * np.pi
    return x

# ---

# The measurement model must convert the state x = [x, y, θ]T into a range and bearing to the landmark. If p is the position
# of a landmark, the range r is r=sqrt((px-x)^2 + (py-y)^2)
# We assume that the sensor provides bearing relative to the orientation of the robot, so we must subtract
# the robot’s orientation from the bearing to get the sensor reading: angle = atan2(py - x[1], px - x[0])

# The residual is y = z − h(x). Suppose z has a
# bearing of 1 ◦ and h(x) is 359 ◦ . Subtracting them gives −358 ◦ . This will throw off the computation of the
# Kalman gain because the correct angular difference is 2 ◦ . So we will have to write code to correctly compute
# the bearing residual.

## as the robot maneuvers different landmarks
## will be visible, so we need to handle a variable number of measurements. The function for the residual in
## the measurement will be passed an array of several measurements, one per landmark.
def residual_h(a, b):
    global arr_npPrediction     # TBD: does it keep all prev data? Do we only need last one (few)?

    residuals = []
    
    i = 0

    if("gps" in dictSensors):
        residuals.append(a[i] - b[i])
        residuals.append(a[i + 1] - b[i + 1])
        i += dictSensors["gps"]
    if("imu" in dictSensors):
        residuals.append(normalize_angle(a[i] - b[i]))              # Orientation (yaw)
        i += 1
        residuals.append(normalize_angle(a[i] - b[i]))      # Angular velocity along z-axis. 
        i += 1
        residuals.append(a[i] - b[i])                       # Linear acceleration along x-axis
        i += 1
        residuals.append(a[i] - b[i])                       # Linear acceleration along y-axis
        i += 1
    if("landmarks" in dictSensors):
        for j in range(0, dictSensors["landmarks"], 2):
            if(arrHideLandmarks[j//2] == True):
                residuals.append(a[i + j] - b[i + j])   # distance
                residuals.append(normalize_angle(a[i + j + 1] - b[i + j + 1]))
            else:
                residuals.append(arr_npPrediction[i + j])
                residuals.append(arr_npPrediction[i + j + 1])

        i += dictSensors["landmarks"]

    return residuals

# ---

def residual_x(a, b):
    y = a - b
    y[2] = normalize_angle(y[2])
    y[3] = normalize_angle(y[3])
    return y    

# the measurement model
# takes a state variable and returns the measurement
# that would correspond to that state
def Hx(x, landmarks):
    global arr_npPrediction

    hx = []

    if("gps" in dictSensors):
        hx.extend(x[[0, 1]])
    if("imu" in dictSensors):
        hx.extend([x[2]])               # theta, orientation
        hx.extend([x[3]])               # vz, angular
        hx.extend([x[4], x[5]])         # ax, ay
    if("landmarks" in dictSensors):
        for lmark in landmarks:
            px, py = lmark
            dist = sqrt((px - x[0])**2 + (py - x[1])**2)
            angle = atan2(py - x[1], px - x[0])
            hx.extend([dist, normalize_angle(angle - x[2])])
    
    arr_npPrediction = np.array(hx)
    return np.array(hx)

# ---

def state_mean(sigmas, Wm):
    x = np.zeros(nNumOfStateParams)
    x[0] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, 0], Wm))     # x
    x[1] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, 1], Wm))     # y

    sum_sin = np.sum(np.dot(np.sin(sigmas[:, 2]), Wm))
    sum_cos = np.sum(np.dot(np.cos(sigmas[:, 2]), Wm))
    x[2] = atan2(sum_sin, sum_cos)              # theta

    sum_sin = np.sum(np.dot(np.sin(sigmas[:, 3]), Wm))
    sum_cos = np.sum(np.dot(np.cos(sigmas[:, 3]), Wm))
    x[3] = atan2(sum_sin, sum_cos)              # angular speed z

    x[4] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, 4], Wm))     # ax
    x[5] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, 5], Wm))     # ay
    return x    

# ---

def z_mean(sigmas, Wm):
    z_count = sigmas.shape[1]
    x = np.zeros(z_count)

    i = 0
    if("gps" in dictSensors):
        x[i] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, i], Wm))
        x[i+1] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:,i+1], Wm))
        i += dictSensors["gps"]

    # imu: orientation (yaw), angular velocity (vx, vy), linear acceleration (ax, ay)
    if("imu" in dictSensors):
        sum_sin = np.sum(np.dot(np.sin(sigmas[:, i]), Wm))
        sum_cos = np.sum(np.dot(np.cos(sigmas[:, i]), Wm))
        x[i] = atan2(sum_sin, sum_cos)                                      # yaw
        i += 1

        sum_sin_vel = np.sum(np.dot(np.sin(sigmas[:, i]), Wm))
        sum_cos_vel = np.sum(np.dot(np.cos(sigmas[:, i]), Wm))
        x[i] = atan2(sum_sin_vel, sum_cos_vel)                          # vz, angular velocity z
        i += 1

        x[i] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, i], Wm))                     # ax
        i += 1
        x[i] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:, i], Wm))                     # ay
        i += 1

    if("landmarks" in dictSensors):
        for z in range(i, z_count, 2):
            x[z] = np.sum(np.dot(sigmas[:,z], Wm))

            sum_sin = np.sum(np.dot(np.sin(sigmas[:, z+1]), Wm))
            sum_cos = np.sum(np.dot(np.cos(sigmas[:, z+1]), Wm))
            x[z+1] = atan2(sum_sin, sum_cos)

        i += dictSensors["landmarks"]

    return x

# ---

#dt = 1.0

def run_localization(initPos, cmds, landmarks, sigma_vel, sigma_steer, sigma_gps, 
    sigma_imu_angle, sigma_imu_angular_vel, sigma_imu_accel, sigma_range, sigma_bearing, ellipse_step=1, step=10):
    
    global arrHideLandmarks
    #global currentCommand

    plt.figure()
    
    points = MerweScaledSigmaPoints(n=nNumOfStateParams, alpha=.00001, beta=2, kappa=0, subtract=residual_x)

    dim_z = 0
    for val in dictSensors.values():
        dim_z += val

    ukf = UKF(dim_x=nNumOfStateParams, dim_z=dim_z,
        fx=move, hx=Hx, dt=dt, points=points, x_mean_fn=state_mean,
        z_mean_fn=z_mean, residual_x=residual_x, residual_z=residual_h)
    ukf.x = np.array(initPos)

    # initial uncertainties (variances) in the robot's state vector
    ukf.P = np.diag([.1, .1, .05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05])

    # measurement noise, dimensions (dim_z x dim_z)
    arrSigmas = []
    if("gps" in dictSensors):
        arrSigmas.extend([sigma_gps**2, sigma_gps**2])
    if("imu" in dictSensors):
        arrSigmas.extend([
            sigma_imu_angle**2, 
            sigma_imu_angular_vel**2, 
            sigma_imu_accel**2, sigma_imu_accel**2])

    # Note: these are initial values. I will adjust them in a cycle below
    # as robot moves and distance to landmarks change, which means sigmas
    # for landmark distance change as well
    if("landmarks" in dictSensors):
        for lmark in landmarks:
            distance_adjusted_sigma_range = sigma_range * sqrt(lmark[0]**2 + lmark[1]**2)
            arrSigmas.extend([distance_adjusted_sigma_range**2, sigma_bearing**2])
    ukf.R = np.diag(arrSigmas)

    # process noise covariance matrix for the state vector
    ukf.Q = np.eye(nNumOfStateParams)*0.0001
    # ukf.Q[0:2, 0:2] = Q_discrete_white_noise(2, 1, var=0.0001)
    # ukf.Q[2, 2] = 0.0001
    sim_pos = ukf.x.copy()
    
    # plot landmarks
    if len(landmarks) > 0:
        plt.scatter(landmarks[:, 0], landmarks[:, 1], marker='s', s=60)

    track = []

    for i, u in enumerate(cmds):
        #currentCommand = u
        #currentCommand[1] += np.random.normal(0, sigma_imu_angular_vel, size=(1))[0]

        nHideLandmarks = np.random.randint(0, 4)
        arrHideLandmarks = np.ones(len(landmarks), dtype=bool)
        arrFalse = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(landmarks)), size=nHideLandmarks, replace=False)
        # Set random elements in arrHideLandmarks to False (hide landmarks)
        arrHideLandmarks[arrFalse] = False

        sim_pos = move(sim_pos, dt/step, u)
        track.append(sim_pos)

        gpsPos = sim_pos[:2] + np.random.normal(0, sigma_gps, size=(2))
        imuYaw = sim_pos[2] + np.random.normal(0, sigma_imu_angle, size=(1))
        imuAngularVelZ = sim_pos[3] + np.random.normal(0, sigma_imu_angular_vel, size=(1))
        imuAccelX = sim_pos[4] + np.random.normal(0, sigma_imu_accel, size=(1))
        imuAccelY = sim_pos[5] + np.random.normal(0, sigma_imu_accel, size=(1))
        
        if i % step == 0:
            if("landmarks" in dictSensors):
                j = 0
                if("gps" in dictSensors):
                    j += dictSensors["gps"] 
                if("imu" in dictSensors):
                    j += dictSensors["imu"]
                for lmark in landmarks:
                    distance_adjusted_sigma_range = sigma_range * sqrt((sim_pos[0] - lmark[0])**2 + (sim_pos[1] - lmark[1])**2)
                    arrSigmas[j] = distance_adjusted_sigma_range**2
                    j += 2
                ukf.R = np.diag(arrSigmas)

            ukf.predict(u=u)
            if i % ellipse_step == 0:
                plot_covariance_ellipse((ukf.x[0], ukf.x[1]), ukf.P[0:2, 0:2], std=6,
                    facecolor='k', alpha=0.3)

            x, y = sim_pos[0], sim_pos[1]
            z = []
            
            if("gps" in dictSensors):
                z.extend(gpsPos[:2])
            if("imu" in dictSensors):
                z.extend(imuYaw)
                z.extend(imuAngularVelZ)
                z.extend(imuAccelX)
                z.extend(imuAccelY)
            if("landmarks" in dictSensors):
                for lmark in landmarks:
                    dx, dy = lmark[0] - x, lmark[1] - y
                    d = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2) + randn()*sigma_range
                    bearing = atan2(lmark[1] - y, lmark[0] - x)
                    a = (normalize_angle(bearing - sim_pos[2] + randn()*sigma_bearing))
                    z.extend([d, a])
            #ukf.update(z)
            ukf.update(z, landmarks=landmarks)

            if i % ellipse_step == 0:
                plot_covariance_ellipse(
                    (ukf.x[0], ukf.x[1]), ukf.P[0:2, 0:2], std=6,
                    facecolor='g', alpha=0.8)

    track = np.array(track)
    plt.plot(track[:, 0], track[:,1], color='k', lw=2)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.title("UKF Robot localization")
    plt.show()

    return ukf

# ---

def turn(v, t0, t1, steps):
    return [[v, a] for a in np.linspace(np.radians(t0), np.radians(t1), steps)]

# ---

#landmarks = np.array([])
landmarks = np.array([[5, 10], [10, 5], [15, 15], [20, 5], [0, 30], [50, 30], [40, 10]])

dictSensors = { #"gps": 2, 
    "imu": 4,
    #"landmarks": 2 * len(landmarks) 
}

dt = 0.1

initPos = [2, 6, np.radians(45), 0., 0., 0.]

# accelerate from a stop
cmds = [[v, .0] for v in np.linspace(0.001, 1.1, 50)]

# Drive straight at 45 degrees (note: initial heading is 45 degrees)
cmds.extend([cmds[-1]]*100)

# turn right
v = cmds[-1][0]
cmds.extend(turn(v, 0, -30, 50))
cmds[-1][1] = 0
cmds.extend([cmds[-1]]*100)

# more right
cmds.extend(turn(v, 0, -15, 50))
cmds[-1][1] = 0
cmds.extend([cmds[-1]]*100)

# turn left
cmds.extend(turn(v, 0, 30, 50))
cmds[-1][1] = 0
cmds.extend([cmds[-1]]*100)

# more left
cmds.extend(turn(v, 0, 15, 50))
cmds[-1][1] = 0
cmds.extend([cmds[-1]]*100)

# more left
cmds.extend(turn(v, 0, 50, 50))
cmds[-1][1] = 0
cmds.extend([cmds[-1]]*400)

ukf = run_localization(initPos, cmds, landmarks,
    sigma_vel=0.1,
    sigma_steer=0.1,
    sigma_gps = 10.0,
    sigma_imu_angle = 0.3,
    sigma_imu_angular_vel = 0.1,
    sigma_imu_accel = 0.1,
    sigma_range=1, 
    sigma_bearing=0.3,
    step=1, ellipse_step=20)

print('final covariance', ukf.P.diagonal())


What do you mean the filter "doesn't use them"?

In code, I have added a way to dynamically tell the filter what sensors to use. Now, if IMU only uses rotation speed an acceleration, and you run the code, it produces the image: trajectory and ellipses for deviations. If you specify (in dictSensors variable) that NO sensors are used, you get exactly same image (uncertainty grows uncontrollably, as should for "blind" Kalman filter). In other words, I did something wrong, so these particular data do not affect filter's results.

You might just have an observability problem. As an example, consider a linear kalman filter with two states: position and velocity along a single axis. If you measure position, then the filter will work great. If you only measure velocity though, the uncertainty on your initial position will never shrink.
You are probably having a similar problem here. If you only measure velocity and acceleration, your filter can never gain any information about its position. The filter would have a good estimate of its velocity though, which should be different than the "blind" filter.
I don't want to take the time to understand all 400+ lines of the code you posted (and I'm not sure what dictSensors = {'imu': 4} means), but hopefully this helps.

No. In case you are describing there (as you mentioned) should be a difference between "no sensor" and "sensor". I think I am missing some part of modelling the thing.
dictSensors = {'imu': 4} means "IMU sensor passes 4 elements of data", in this case, orientation, angular speed, ax, ay. Orientation is used by filter. angular speed, ax, ay - are not.

The problem was in the way state parameters persist between calls to Kalman's predict/update. As there was no conversion between state and expected sensor data for acceleration, it was lost.
I will post the working code to https://robotics.snowcron.com as soon as I clean it up and fix bugs.
